# Get the percentage rate of people in attendance

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a list of departments and the percentage of people in that department who will be attending.

Output:

- SALES = 30% attending
- ACCOUNTING = 15% attending

TABLE EMP:

```
EMPID FNAME LNAME    DEPT
001......John......Lock...Sales
002......Lisa......Conrad...Accounting
003......Jerry.....Forts...Billing
004......Sara......Duval...Sales
```

TABLE ATTENDANCE:

```
EMPID  PARTY_ATTEND
001......Y
002......N
003......N
004......Y
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? I have some code written down but I don't know how to tie everything together. I was planning on using JOIN and some counter, but this is what I just have so far...

```
select fname, lname, a.party_attend, a.empid from emp

select count(*) 
  from attendance a
 inner join emp on a.empid = emp.empid
 where a.party_attend = 'Y'
```

Then the math part I'm not sure...

```
select sum(  )/count(*)*100
```

Help? My brain is fried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  empid NUMBER,
  fname VARCHAR2(20),
  dept VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE attendance (
  empid NUMBER,
  party_attend VARCHAR2(1)
);

INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1,' John', 'Sales');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (2,' Lisa', 'Accounting');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (3,' Jerry', 'Billing');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (4,' Sara', 'Sales');

INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (1, 'Y');
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (2, 'N');
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (3, 'N');
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (4, 'Y');

COMMIT;

SELECT
    e.dept,
    COUNT(DECODE(att.party_attend, 'Y', 1, NULL)) / COUNT(1) * 100 AS percentage
  FROM
    emp e JOIN attendance att ON (e.empid = att.empid)
GROUP BY e.dept;
```

Output:

```
DEPT                 PERCENTAGE
-------------------- ----------
Accounting                    0 
Billing                       0 
Sales                       100
```

The output is not what you expect, because in your data all employees that attend the party are from sales department...

Comment: Yes sorry about that, the output I just made up, but this is what I'm looking for on how to use the join and the math part correctly